# IntelliJ Gradle HotSwap building unrelated modules

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, multi-project, hotswap

I am having trouble getting Gradle HotSwap to work reasonably with IntelliJ IDEA.

We have a Java setup which consists of some basic modules, then some country variants that use these basic modules and then even country variants of the GUI.

The structure looks like this:

```
Root
+--- buildSrc
|    \--- [Some custom precompiled groovy script plugins]
+--- CoreModules
|    \--- [Some modules]
+--- CountryVariants
|    \--- [A module for each country variant]
+--- GuiCountryVariants
|    \--- [A module for each special country GUI variant] 
\--- build.gradle (to be able to run tests for all modules at once)
```

Which means, we always build and run a specific country.
For example, here are the dependencies for the GUI specific runnable CH country variant:

```
runtimeClasspath - Runtime classpath of source set 'main'.
+--- project :CoreModuleG
|    \--- project :GUICore
|         +--- project :CoreModuleB
|         |    \--- project :CoreModuleC
|         |         \--- project :CoreModuleP
|         |              \--- project :CoreModuleE
|         \--- project :GUICoreModuleG
+--- project :CountryVariantCH
|    \--- project :CoreModuleB (*)
\--- project :GUICore (*)
```

And by contrast, country variant US has:

```
runtimeClasspath - Runtime classpath of source set 'main'.
+--- project :CoreModuleB
|    \--- project :CoreModuleC
|         \--- project :CoreModuleP
|              \--- project :CoreModuleE
\--- project :CoreModuleG
     \--- project :GUICore
          +--- project :CoreModuleB (*)
          \--- project :GUICoreModuleG
```

Now, if I start my country variant for CH with a Gradle JavaExec task, it will of course only compile all modules needed for CH, and it will for example **not** compile country variant US, as expected.
The following is a (shortened) excerpt of the startup:

```
Gradle Daemon started in 2 s 367 ms
> Task :buildSrc:jar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :GuiVariantCH:processResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :CoreModuleE:jar SKIPPED
> Task :GUICoreModuleG:jar
> Task :CoreModuleP:jar
> Task :CoreModuleC:jar
> Task :GUICore:jar
> Task :CoreModuleG:jar
> Task :CountryVariantCH:jar
> Task :CoreModuleB:jar
> Task :GUIVariantCH:classes
Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:56923', transport: 'socket'
> Task :GUIVariantCH:run
```

But if I then change a class and use "Run > Debugging Actions > Reload Changed Classes" it builds every single module, including all 24 country variants:

```
11:03:47: Executing ':classes :testClasses [list of all core modules for tasks :classes and :testClasses] [list of all country variant modules for tasks :classes and :testClasses] [list of all GUI country variant modules for tasks :classes and :testClasses]'...

[long list of executions of all :classes and :testClasses tasks]

> Task :CountryVariantZA:classes
> Task :CountryVariantZA:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :CountryVariantZA:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
> Task :GUICountryVariantCH:classes
> Task :GUICountryVariantCH:compileTestJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :GUICountryVariantCH:testClasses UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 17s
```

But since I'm running the `:GUICountryVariantCH:run` task, I would expect that only `:GUICountryVariantCH:classes` and `:GUICountryVariantCH:testClasses` tasks are run.

Of course, if I previously compiled all country variants, it is faster than 17 seconds. But it still is executing tasks it shouldn't and thus takes longer than needed.

So, is this caused by a wrong Gradle configuration, a wrong IntelliJ configuration (IntelliJ IDEA 2023.2.2 (Community Edition)) or is this an actual IntelliJ bug?

Has anybody had success with hot swap in a similar situation?

I searched far and wide but nobody seems to have this specific problem.

What I found is [this plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/14832-single-hotswap) which lets you hotswap a single file, so I could use this plugin or of course "Compile and reload file" in the context menu within a file.

But I still feel hotswap should be able to work by not invoking `:classes` but rather `:specificModuleStarted:classes`. Because if you changed multiple files, reloading just this one particular file is not what you want.

Comment: Does the issue persist if you use "Reload single file" option described here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/altering-the-program-s-execution-flow.html#reload_classes

Comment: @romanv-jb Well, it kinda works. It executes `:classes` for whichever module your file is in. So if it's a file in my GUICountry, it will reload everything needed. But if I make adjustments to a file in my GUICountry and to a file in CoreModuleB and use "Compile and Reload File" in the CoreModuleB, then the changes to my GUICountry are not reloaded (because the GUI depends on the Core and not vice-versa).
So it works if you only change 1 file and kinda works if you change multiple files.
Having the "Reload Changed Classes" work as expected would be better though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be a known issue [IDEA-304595](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-304595/Reload-Changed-Classes-has-compilation-scope-of-whole-project-instead-of-only-required-modules).

Make sure to upvote it to raise its' priority for the developers!